# What value I need to give for kwargs here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm converting my code: 
`start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn, addr))` from python 2
Using code from internet:

```
threading.Thread(target=some_callable_function,
       args=(tuple, of, args),
       kwargs={'dict': 'of', 'keyword': 'args'},
   ).start()
```

Can you help to convert it?

```
threading.Thread(clientthread,
        args=(conn, addr),
```

And here I'm stuck in kwargs. What I need to write in kwargs?

I'm still learning,please don't be strict:)

Comment: Have you done any research on kwargs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an optional argument and in your case you should leave it blank. It's for [named arguments](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html#usage-of-kwargs) which you don't have.